# Strophe js how to get last message of all user in rostered users

Tags: ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

I am using Strophe js for ejabberd chat application.
how to

> get last message of all user who all rostered with logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have mod_mam enabled and properly configured, it can store all the messages of all the users, and later you can request them, following https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html